Azure Key Vault Secret Expiry Notifications
In Azure Key Vault, we have multiple secrets that will eventually expire. Can we configure settings to receive notifications both before and after their expiration? I tried using Azure Alerts, but this method relies on email notifications, which is not ideal because the owner or user of the key vault might change over time. Therefore, I need to consider a different approach.
 I tried this method to send notification

the owner or user of the key vault might change over time - send the notification to more than 1 user seems a reasonable thing to do. Or, use a mailing list instead.

Also, you can configure not only emails but also SMS, webhooks etc and integrate it with Logic Apps, MS Teams and other applications.


Azure Key Vault Secret Expiry Notifications.

I agree with Rui Jarimba's comment that you can definitely send the notification to multiple users by adding multiple email addresses in the "To" field of the "Send an email" action in your Logic App.

You can simplify recipient management by creating a mailing list and using its email address in the "To" field of the "Send an email" action.
This allows you to easily update the list of recipients through the mailing list settings, avoiding the need to modify the Logic App whenever there are changes in who receives notifications.
You have the flexibility to configure various notification methods such as emails, SMS, webhooks, and more, integrating them seamlessly with Azure Logic Apps, Microsoft Teams, and other applications.

You can follow this SO-thread by rithwik bojja to create alert and send an email notification to the users using logic app.
Reference:
azure key vault secret expiry notification - Microsoft Q&A by MayankBargali-MSFT.
